# Photoswipe redirects to image url

Tags: wordpress, popup, gallery, portfolio, photoswipe

I am developing a website in Wordpress and I need to incorporate a portfolio. I am using Visual Portfolio with PhotoSwipe.

I leave an example page: http://www.aurepromociones.es/residencial-la-dehesa

The problem is that when I click on one of the images in the gallery, the popup opens, but immediately redirects me to the page of the photo.

What I need is to remove that redirect as I only want the popup function.

I don't know if anyone can help me.